# How to give access for review Google App Script web page?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, gmail

I'm create Google App script web page and i share link with my friends. that request access for view page. I received this mail for my friend.
[image]

However i cannot give permission for friend. after press "Open sharing settings" it open my script but there hasn't any changes.

1. This can be reason of Google drive Access problem,
2. This can be reason of Google Sheet Access problem,
3. This can be reason of G Mail authentication problem,

Comment: so you oppened sharing did you add them then?

Comment: I'm opened, but there has not any popup menu,box, button for approve the Access. so i cannot add them.  i create another Script and replace this code and share it with friends. After that I added them using that Script.

Comment: Is it a bound script (attached to a Google Sheet)? If so, you have to give access on the sheet as well as the web app. You should also make sure the web app settings are "Execute as me" rather than the visiting user, otherwise _they_ are prompted to authenticate, which can cause issues.

Comment: yes, it is bound Script, I'm did not give access for sheet. thank you Brian,